# I want to pass large data from work manager to my fragment without using room

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-workmanager

I want to pass the list that i get from work manager api request to my fragment so I can update adapter of recyclerview. I don't want to use Room since the list is larger than 10 Kb but instead I'm using runOnUIThread so I can pass them. I got fragment instance by using findFragmentByTag but I don't know which is the best way to pass the list to the adapter

Here is my code:
Please help me :)

```
try {
        val groupsResponse = client.groups().execute()
        if (!groupsResponse.isSuccessful) return result

        val list = groupsResponse.body()!!

        activity?.runOnUiThread {

            activity as ViewPagerActivity

            val viewPager = activity.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)
            val fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(
                "android:switcher:" +
                        R.id.view_pager + ":" + viewPager.currentItem
            )


             //how to pass data to adapter?

        }


        Result.SUCCESS


    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace()
        result = Result.FAILURE


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the instance of the fragment you can cast it to your concrete implementation and then call a method you define.

But you should not do it this way. On configuration changes the fragment will be recreated. So you should use a ViewModel and the ViewModel will hand the data to the fragment. 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get instances of activities and fragments inside your worker class?  If so, please don't do that - it's not going to work properly.  The whole point of WorkManager is that your work can execute in the background when your foreground UI is not up, meaning all of those things can be null.

Instead, in your fragment, observe the status of your worker to get the relevant output.  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation